# SQL to always return false

Tags: sql, oracle

I Want to write a sql query which will should always return false.

if i write

```
select 1 from dual where 1=2;
```

nothing is returned. how can i use where 1=2 which always returns "false".

Comment: A select statement cannot return a Boolean value like `false`.  You could return 1 to denote true and 0 to denote false e.g. `select case when 1=2 then 1 else 0 end flag from dual;`

Comment: Don't see the reason for this. You're not populating a PL/SQL variable with this are you? Perhaps you can describe what problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is nothing where 1 = 2.

```
select false from dual
```

(Substitute the value you want it to return for false.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `plsql` and `plsqldeveloper` tags I have to believe you're using Oracle. As it turns out there is no BOOLEAN type in the Oracle database product, although a BOOLEAN type does exist in PL/SQL. When I find a need to include a "true or false" value in the database I'll create a CHAR(1) column and constrain it to contain only values of 'T' or 'F'; thus, if 'F' is acceptable as a "false" value you could do something like:

```
SELECT 'F' FROM DUAL
```

If you don't like 'F' you can substitute any value you'd care to choose for the 'F'.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use

Select 1